# How to change the sorting priority for special characters in file names

Tags: imac, filesystem, macos, sort

In **Finder.app**, as per the default sort order, the files and folders whose name begin with an underscore character `_` appear before the hidden files, i.e. ones whose name being with a dot `.`.

[image]

I would like to be able to see the ones whose name begin with a `.` character to appear before the ones whose name begin with a `_` character, as well as other special characters.

As I recall, in older versions of Mac OS X, this feature was under `System Preferences → International`. However I am unable to find it in macOS High Sierra. How do I change this setting.

Comment: System Preferences > Language & Region

Comment: @njboot - Care to expand?

Comment: `System Preferences → Language & Region` is a replacement for `System Preferences → International` from older versions of Mac OS X. However, there doesn't appear to be any setting to tweak the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Allan No, because I don't know what the OP did before to enable this. I'm just pointing out where those preferences are now located.

Comment: @njboot - My point is, I can't discern what you're referencing to so I doubt the OP will either.

Comment: System Preferences → Language & Region was the first place I looked.

Comment: I'd be ok modifying system files if there's no GUI setting.

Comment: @Allan uh, referencing where the OP said the solution was previously found? Read the whole Q...